# How to get a list of all Display Methods in a table?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I need to get a list of all display methods in a table, and I can't seem to find anything about this on the web.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On display methods [`displayType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dictmethod.displaytype(AX.60).aspx) is set to [`DisplayFunctionType::Get`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dictmethod.displaytype(AX.60).aspx).

---

```cs
DictTable dt = new DictTable(tableNum(VendTable));
DictMethod dm;
DisplayFunctionType dft;
DictType dEdt;

int mtdCnt = dt.objectMethodCnt();
int i;

setPrefix(strFmt("Table: %1", dt.name()));
for (i = 1; i <= mtdCnt; i++)
{
    dm = dt.objectMethodObject(i);
    dft = dm.displayType();

    if (dft == DisplayFunctionType::Get)
    {
        dEdt = new DictType(dm.returnId());

        info(strFmt("Method: %1 (Label: %2)", dm.name(), dEdt.label()));
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfect. Do you also know how  to get the labels from the EDT/Base enum that it returns?

Comment: @Heygar use [`DictType.label`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dicttype.label(AX.60).aspx). See updated example.

Comment: Amazing! I was so close myself, but this was much simpler and better.